# Is there a way to use sql bulk insert without using datatable from generic list?

Tags: datatable, bulkinsert, generic-list

I have a generic list contains about six and a half million. I would like to insert this generic list to database by using sql bulk insert. But a datatable is necessary for using sql bulk insert. Convert generic list to datatable takes too much time. So how can I use sql bulk insert without using datatable ?

**EDIT:**

I use `MSSQL SERVER` and `.NET FrameWork`

I would like to just use it with a generic list.

Comment: Which DBMS, mysql , sql server etc and which framework?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write them. I have edited my question.

Comment: By Bulk insert, do you mean insert a bulk of data, or sql server's native bulk insert facility, which works from a file. Why have you got 6.5 million records in memory, on the face of it doesn't seem like a wise thing to do.

Comment: Yes I wanted to tell to insert a bulk of data. I don't use a file. I create a new list by using some process in memory. I have tried to insert each one record to database. It takes too much more time than bulk insert. What can i do else ?

Comment: Have a look for sql server bulk insert command, it's not a gimme, as it needs a file and that file must be accessible by the accounts the service is running as, but its much much faster. With your current approach the impact you can have is severely limited.

Comment: In this case, Does not the generic list need to convert or write to a file ? This also will not lose time?

Comment: Well of course it will take time, nowhere near as much as sending inserts one at a time to the server though. That many records client side is not easy to recover from, there's no cheap option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a custom datareader that have been inherited IDataReader.  I have achieved like below :

```
public class CustomDataReader<T> : IDataReader
    {
        private readonly IEnumerator<T> list;
        private readonly List<PropertyInfo> properties = new List<PropertyInfo>();

        public CustomDataReader(IEnumerable<T> list)
        {
            this.list = list.GetEnumerator();
            var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            foreach (var propertyInfo in props)
            {
                properties.Add(propertyInfo);
            }
        }

        #region IDataReader Members

        public void Close()
        {
            list.Dispose();
        }

        public int Depth
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public DataTable GetSchemaTable()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool IsClosed
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public bool NextResult()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool Read()
        {
            return list.MoveNext();
        }

        public int RecordsAffected
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        #endregion

        #region IDisposable Members

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Close();
        }

        #endregion

        #region IDataRecord Members

        public int FieldCount
        {
            get { return properties.Count; }
        }

        public bool GetBoolean(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public byte GetByte(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public long GetBytes(int i, long fieldOffset, byte[] buffer, int bufferoffset, int length)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public char GetChar(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public long GetChars(int i, long fieldoffset, char[] buffer, int bufferoffset, int length)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public IDataReader GetData(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public string GetDataTypeName(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public DateTime GetDateTime(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public decimal GetDecimal(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public double GetDouble(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Type GetFieldType(int i)
        {
            return properties[i].PropertyType;
        }

        public float GetFloat(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Guid GetGuid(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public short GetInt16(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public int GetInt32(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public long GetInt64(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public string GetName(int i)
        {
            return properties[i].Name;
        }

        public int GetOrdinal(string name)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public string GetString(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object GetValue(int i)
        {
            return properties[i].GetValue(list.Current, null);
        }

        public int GetValues(object[] values)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool IsDBNull(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object this[string name]
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public object this[int i]
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        #endregion
    }


public static void BulkInsert<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, string connStr, string tableName)
{ 
    using (var reader = new CustomDataReader<T>(list))
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            using (var sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                sbc.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                sbc.WriteToServer(reader);
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```